# How to remove this kitchen faucet cartridge?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I haven't been able to determine the make/model but doing some research it looks like possibly Pfister. Either way, the cartridge part is sticking and handle is very difficult to use. I am trying to remove but I am not sure what the next step is/how to remove it. It *may* be [this process](http://s2.img-b.com/faucetdirect.com/mediabase/specifications/pfister/533327/pfister_gt26_4n_explodedparts_912.pdf).  But step 23 is clearly a [bit different](http://s2.img-b.com/faucetdirect.com/mediabase/specifications/pfister/533327/pfister_gt26_4n_installation_502.pdf).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Turns out it was an older Pfister. I emailed their customer support for some insight and they are sending a removal tool, cartridge and new retainer ring. Great customer support, impressed. Doesn't happen often.